# Parsing a string works not as expected

Tags: java, regex, string

There is a string which I trying to parse by "|" symbol:

> 1-20|21-40|41-60|61-80|81-100|101-120|121-131

```
String[] arr = text.split("|");

for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
    System.out.println( arr[i] );
}
```

It parses to every character, like

```
1
-
2
0
|
2
1
...
```

How to parse the source string for elements like:

> 1-20

Comment: Escape the split string: `"\\|"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` is a special character in Java's regex syntax that means a logical "or" between two matching groups. If you want to match the `|` literal, you need to escape it:

```
String[] arr = text.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

This `|` is a special character in *regular expression(s)*, you need to escape it. Like,

```
String[] arr = text.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a metacaracter in regex. Escape it:

```
String[] splitValues = text.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

escape the pipe using  `"\\|"`

```
String[] arr = text.split("\\|");
```